# ADOtable refresh

Tags: delphi, delphi-xe2, tadotable

I have an ADOTable with 3 columns 'ID', 'Number' and 'Used'. The table contains some pre-generated numbers. When I use a number I just set the 'USED' to 1 and then I filter the table to get only the unused numbers.

Now the small problem: say I pull a number and set the 'USED' to 1. I see the column updated in Access, if I try to pull different number with Delphi it gives me the same, so I think the ADO table has not been refreshed. I tried to use `refresh` but it did not work. The only way I can make it work is to use `Active := false` and then `Active := true`. I think there should be more elegant way to do it. Any idea?

Comment: did you try 'adoTable.requery;' ?

Answer (score 1):

Set `CursorLocation` of your `AdoTable` to `clUseServer` and `AdoTable.refresh` will work

Comment: it seems the requery did the job, but this also a good suggestion. thank you.